# Im using a thread that uses callback for function and passing 2 arguments. However I keep getting callback error

Tags: c, multithreading, callback, rtos

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "rtos.h"

DigitalOut led(LED1);
DigitalIn switch1(PC_9); //turns on the carpark
DigitalIn switch2(PC_8); //car entry
DigitalIn switch3(PC_10); //car exit

void BeginDisplay(int *count,int *space_count){
    Thread::signal_wait(0x2);
    int avail=0;
    while(true){
        if(*space_count<=10){
            avail = *count - *space_count;
            printf("\nAvailable space %d\n\r",avail);
        }
        else{
            printf("\ncar park full\n\r");
        }
    }
}
void BeginCarPark(int *count,int *space_count){

    Thread::signal_wait(0x1);
    while(true){
        if(count==0){
            printf("\n Car Park is full");
        }
        else{
            printf("\n Car Park is available");
        }
        if(!(switch2 == 0)){ //car entring carpark
            count = count - 1;
            if(count<=0){
                space_count = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(!(switch3 == 0)){ //car leaving carpark
            count = count + 1;
            space_count = count;   
        }
    //return space_count;
    }
}

int main(){
    Thread CarPark;
    Thread Display;
    int space_count = 0;
    int space_capacity = 10;
    printf("\n Car Park is Closed\n\r");
    while(1){
        
        Display.start(callback(BeginDisplay,&space_capacity,&space_count));
        CarPark.start(callback(BeginCarPark,&space_capacity,&space_count));
        while(!(switch1 == 0))
        {
            
            CarPark.signal_set(0x1);
            Display.signal_set(0x2);
            
        }
    }

}
```

In the code I keep getting error for the line

```
Display.start(callback(BeginDisplay,&space_capacity,&space_count));
```

The error is

```
Error: No instance of overloaded function "callback"  matches the
argument list in "main.cpp".
```

I really new to using threads and I couldn't really find any solution to my problem. I hope I can get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the callback the address of the variables you want to modify, not the variables themselves. The compiler is complaining because it cannot determine the type of the variables you are passing, and it doesn't know how to convert them to a function pointer.